# How to handle temporary saves on GIT?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-commit

I have been playing around with GIT and I am getting the hang of it. I do have a small question relating to temporary saves. Say I create a feature branch off of the main branch and do some implementation on the feature branch. So at the end of the day I want to just save the implementation on the feature branch, do I just commit and push it to the remote feature repository or do I create another branch for the temporary save?

Could someone please shed some light on it.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+temporary+save+changes

Comment: One reason to use branches is for temporary work.  
Your **feature** branch can exists in both local and remote repositories (github, bitbucket, or whatever).  
After finishing your feature, you merge your work with the main branch, probably named as **master**

Comment: You can just commit and push it to the remote feature repository! You can continue working on this feature branch next day. 
Once the feature implementation is done, and you are confident, you can merge it back to the main branch and delete the feature branch if the feature is 100% done.
Or, if you decided to obsolete the feature, you can just leave it or delete the feature branch, the main branch will never be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must commit and push it to the feature branch. If your remote repository doesn't have this branch, it will be created automatically. When your feature is fully implemented, you can merge your **feature** branch with the main branch of your repository.

I found this little article which might give you a good overview of git branches:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-branches